# Android: Width and Height of View After Orientation Change

Tags: android, width, orientation, screen-orientation, onconfigurationchanged

I need to get the width and height of a WebView and pass them in the query string of the URL I am loading in the WebView. I have found a way to do this in onResume(). Since the width and height are not calculated at this point, I post a Runnable to the WebView to be queued for after the UI loads.

Here's my problem: when the orientation changes, I am handling it in onConfigurationChanged. When I try to post a Runnable in onConfigurationChanged to the WebView, the WebView's width and height end up being the old orientation's width and height. At what point can I intercept the new width and height after orientation change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `ViewTreeObserver`, for an example check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8245468/757073

Answer (score 0):

Try in onPostResume. This gets called after onResume, which is supposed to be called when it gets ready to put it on screen.

Comment: Neither of those are called in this particular instance. The activity handles configurations with onConfigurationChanged so the activity is not restarted.

Comment: hmmmm....why do you need the width and height of the webview? maybe there is another way to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

This only works with the parent view or getRootView() it returns the same ht and wd for the child view.