# How to get width and height of GridView after onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, gridview, configuration

I want to get width and height of my GridView after onConfigurationChanged so when I swing  my device from landscape to portrait I want to get the new width and height values of my grid

Answer (score 1):

See [How to get NEW width/height of root layout in onConfigurationChanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524683/how-to-get-new-width-height-of-root-layout-in-onconfigurationchanged)

**The view is NOT redrawn in onResume()** - drawing the view is not a part of this lifecycle (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).  You'll need to use `android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` to be notified when the view is re-drawn.

Note however that I've observed this method doesn't always work as intended.  After a configuration change (rotation), if I don't remove the listener, the method fires 3 times - the first 2 have the old values, and the 3rd time has the new values.  If I remove the listener immediately after it is notified, I still get the old values.  (But if you don't remove the listener, you'll probably need to implement some hacks to prevent code from running again.)